# Reshaping the HRS data from wide to long format and creating a time variable

Tags: r, reshape2, panel-data

I have the following dataset (containing around 25 more variables other than Weight = W and Height = H), all spanning 10 years.

Currently it has the following form and **no** time index.

```
df <- structure(list(data = structure(1:4, .Label = c("Ind_1", "Ind_2", 
"Ind_3", "Ind_4"), class = "factor"), r1weight = c(56, 76, 87, 64
), r2weight = c(57, 75, 88, 66), r3weight = c(56, 76, 87, 65), r4weight = c(56L, 
73L, 85L, 63L), r5weight = c(55L, 77L, 84L, 65L), r1height = c(151L, 163L, 
173L, 153L), r2height = c(154L, 164L, NA, 154L), r3height = c(NA, 165L, NA, 
152L), r4height = c(153L, 162L, 172L, 154L), r5height = c(152,161,171,154)), class = 
"data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -4L)) 

  data  r1w r2w r3w r4w r5w r1h r2h r3h r4h r5h
1 Ind_1  56  57  56  56  55 151 154  NA 153 152
2 Ind_2  76  75  76  73  77 163 164 165 162 161
3 Ind_3  87  88  87  85  84 173  NA  NA 172 171
4 Ind_4  64  66  65  63  65 153 154 152 154 154`
```

I need to add time variable and reshape to long format, hopefully getting something like this.

```
dflong <- structure(list(time = structure(1:20, .Label = c("1", "2", 
     "3", "4", "5", "1","2","3","4","5", "1","2","3","4","5","1","2","3","4","5"), 
     class = "factor"), Ind = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4), W = c(56,57,56,56,55,76,75,76,73,77,87,88,87,85,84,64,66,65,63,65),
     H = c(151,154,NA,153,152,163,164,165,162,161,173,NA,NA,172,171,153,154,152,154,154)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

which looks

```
   time Ind  W   H
1     1   1 56 151
2     2   1 57 154
3     3   1 56  NA
4     4   1 56 153
5     5   1 55 152
6     1   2 76 163
7     2   2 75 164
8     3   2 76 165
9     4   2 73 162
10    5   2 77 161
11    1   3 87 173
12    2   3 88  NA
13    3   3 87  NA
14    4   3 85 172
15    5   3 84 171
16    1   4 64 153
17    2   4 66 154
18    3   4 65 152
19    4   4 63 154
20    5   4 65 154`
```

I tried to use the `reshape2`-command and so far I've got:

```
library(reshape2)
dflong <- melt(df,id.vars = c("idhhpn",r1w-r10w, r1h-r10h (help writing compactly),
     time(needs help constructing) )`
```

I dont want to write "r1w, r2w, r3w", but more like r1weight-r10weight so I dont have to write all 10 time instances for all 25 variable.

So far I've got to this point

[image]

by using the follwing code

```
melt <- melt(setDT(HRSdata), measure = patterns("idhhpn", "srhlt", "highbp", "diabetes", "cancer", "lungev", "heartp", "strokev", "psychev", "arth", "obese", "agey", "marpart", "male", "black", "hispan", "logass", "logdebt", "atotal", "debt", "lths", "hsorged", "somehs", "scorAA", "bachelor", "graduate", "works62", "works65", "momagey", "dadagey", "dadalive", "momalive", "vigact3", "smokesn"), 
     value.name = c("idhhpn", "srhlt", "highbp", "diabetes", "cancer", "lungev", "heartp", "strokev", "psychev", "arth", "obese", "agey", "marpart", "male", "black", "hispan", "logass", "logdebt", "atotal", "debt", "lths", "hsorged", "somehs", "scorAA", "bachelor", "graduate", "works62", "works65", "momagey", "dadagey", "dadalive", "momalive", "vigact3", "smokesn"), 
     variable.name = "time")[, 
      idhhpn := as.integer(sub("\\D+", "", HRSdata))][order(idhhpn)][, .(time, idhhpn, srhlt, highbp, diabetes, cancer, lungev, heartp, strokev, psychev, arth, obese, agey, marpart, male, black, hispan, logass, logdebt, atotal, debt, lths, hsorged, somehs, scorAA, bachelor, graduate, works62, works65, momagey, dadagey, dadalive, momalive, vigact3, smokesn        )]
```

Comment: Does it have to be reshape2? I could come up with a solution easily, but it would be using tidyr's `gather`

Comment: Can you try by only keeping the `idhhpn` and the variables to melt in the `measure` column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option using `data.table` that makes use of the `measure/patterns` would be to use `melt`.  In the example, the column names have common `patterns` as 'weight', 'height' which we specify it in `measure` parameter to convert it to 'long' format, then extract the numeric part with `sub` to create 'Ind'

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df), measure = patterns("weight", "height"), value.name = c("W", "H"), 
  variable.name = "time")[, 
    Ind := as.integer(sub("\\D+", "", data))][order(Ind)][, .(time, Ind, W, H)]
#   time Ind  W   H
# 1:    1   1 56 151
# 2:    2   1 57 154
# 3:    3   1 56  NA
# 4:    4   1 56 153
# 5:    5   1 55 152
# 6:    1   2 76 163
# 7:    2   2 75 164
# 8:    3   2 76 165
# 9:    4   2 73 162
#10:    5   2 77 161
#11:    1   3 87 173
#12:    2   3 88  NA
#13:    3   3 87  NA
#14:    4   3 85 172
#15:    5   3 84 171
#16:    1   4 64 153
#17:    2   4 66 154
#18:    3   4 65 152
#19:    4   4 63 154
#20:    5   4 65 154
```

Comment: what do you mean with "setDT" ? what do I write here instead? and when you write "ind" do I have to write my id-variable which is "idhhpn"? Or do I just keep your code exactly as is. I'm sorry but I don't understand what I need to change in your code and what to keep, but I could really need some help.

Comment: @EmilKrabbe `setDT` is a function to convert the 'data.frame' to `data.table` so that it can access the data.table methods.  It should be the same for other objects from convrerting to data.table.  If the object is already data.table, it is not needed.  Regarding the Ind, yes, you have to change it to the column name in your actual dataset..  Please let me know if you stumble upon anything

Comment: I wish I could send you pictures of my code but I don't think I can here. I wrote all my variables in you code. So where you wrote "W" and "H" I wrote ally my 24, but it doesnt seem to work unfortunately... hmmm can I show you somehow?

Comment: @EmilKrabbe  Lets say you have 12 Weight and 12 Height column names with pattern "W" or "H".  It would still be 2 columns as these are converted from wide format to long format.  Can you please check if that is the case

Comment: 3: In `[.data.table`(melt(setDT(HRSdata), measure = patterns("idhhpn",  :
  Supplied 331 items to be assigned to 250890 items of column 'idhhpn' (recycled leaving remainder of 323 items).
4: In `[.data.table`(melt(setDT(HRSdata), measure = patterns("idhhpn",  :
  Coerced integer RHS to double to match the type of the target column (column 2 named 'idhhpn'). If the target column's type double is correct, it's best for efficiency to avoid the coercion and create the RHS as type double.

Comment: @EmilKrabbe  If the column type are different, you will get that warning though. But, it is a friendly warning.  If you want to remove that warning, make sure the columns are of the same type before doing the melt

Comment: Ah okay thanks. There is one more thing. First of all yes I can see that my data is not a `data frame` but a `data table`. Also I think it works now BUT I get `NA`'s in my ID-variable which cannot be true because I deleted all individuals who had `NA` as an ID. So I think something went wrong somewhere.. but otherwise it works well

Comment: @EmilKrabbe  There can be NA rows if the number of 'W' columns and number of 'H' columns are not the same.  Is that the case?

Comment: I made sure that there are 10 columns of each variable. Even my 9 dummy variables I had to create extra so that I would have 10 in total (even though being male doesn't change)

Comment: @EmilKrabbe  With the example data, I am not getting any NA for 'Ind' column.  Can you please update the `dput` of an example that creates this issue

Comment: Below "So far I've got..." I posted pictures of my code and my output. Btw thank you a million :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190641/discussion-between-akrun-and-emil-krabbe).

Answer (score 2):

A `tidyverse` approach using `gather` and `spread` would be

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  gather(time, ind, -data) %>%
  separate(time, into = c("indName", "time")) %>%
  spread(indName, ind)


#    data time  H  W
#1  Ind_1   1 151 56
#2  Ind_1   2 154 57
#3  Ind_1   3  NA 56
#4  Ind_1   4 153 56
#5  Ind_1   5 152 55
#6  Ind_2   1 163 76
#7  Ind_2   2 164 75
#8  Ind_2   3 165 76
#9  Ind_2   4 162 73
#10 Ind_2   5 161 77
#11 Ind_3   1 173 87
#12 Ind_3   2  NA 88
#13 Ind_3   3  NA 87
#14 Ind_3   4 172 85
#15 Ind_3   5 171 84
#16 Ind_4   1 153 64
#17 Ind_4   2 154 66
#18 Ind_4   3 152 65
#19 Ind_4   4 154 63
#20 Ind_4   5 154 65
```

Same solution but with the revised variable names of "r[num][varname]" (by @iod):

```
df %>%
  gather(time, ind, -data) %>%
  mutate(time=gsub("r([0-9])","\\1_",time)) %>%
  separate(time, into = c("time","indName")) %>%
  spread(indName, ind)

    data time height weight
1  Ind_1    1    151     56
2  Ind_1    2    154     57
3  Ind_1    3     NA     56
4  Ind_1    4    153     56
5  Ind_1    5    152     55
6  Ind_2    1    163     76
7  Ind_2    2    164     75
8  Ind_2    3    165     76
9  Ind_2    4    162     73
10 Ind_2    5    161     77
11 Ind_3    1    173     87
12 Ind_3    2     NA     88
13 Ind_3    3     NA     87
14 Ind_3    4    172     85
15 Ind_3    5    171     84
16 Ind_4    1    153     64
17 Ind_4    2    154     66
18 Ind_4    3    152     65
19 Ind_4    4    154     63
20 Ind_4    5    154     65
```

Comment: Let's say I have variables "W", "H" , "bmi", "pulse", "age".  Would that be:                                                        library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  gather(time, ind, -data) %>%
  separate(time, into = c("W", "H", "bmi", "pulse", "age")) %>%
  spread(W, ind). And how does R now that my variables r1age, r2age, ..., r10age belong together??

Comment: This solution assumes all variables are in the format `WORD_[num]`, e.g. "W_2" or "bmi_4" - it will work with all of them. It will NOT work with something like "r1age". That's what `separate` does: it breaks the variable name (which has been gathered into the `ind` column) into two parts, at the underscore (a period will also work). No need to list out all the vars as long as they all have this format.

Comment: I edited the solution to replace the confusing "W" helper-column with "indName".

Comment: Try running each segment by itself to see how this solution works one step at a time: the `gather` creates one long molten format with all the H's and W's in one column. `Separate` creates two columns - one with either H or W, and the other with the time indicator. Then `spread` takes the H/W column and recasts them with the "ind" column to create a separate column for each of the variables.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @iod, just to add, if your columns name does not have underscore or spaces you can add custom separator in `sep` argument of `separate`. It depends on what your column name are.

Comment: I will try to follow the description given, thanks. Also I edited my question to resemble the real variable names better (I did use abbreviations though, h = height and w = weight)

Comment: Added a revised solution based on @RonakShah's that works with your new variable name format

Comment: and when you write "indname" I have to put all my 25 variables here right? seperated by a comma maybe?

Comment: ok..great ..thanks @iod , I was trying to use the `sep` argument here but it looks you can't directly use it unless you change the names of columns.

Comment: @EmilKrabbe no..the `gather` step would make it into long format for the same reason so that you don't have to put all the column names. The updated solution by @iod works on your new data. You just have to run it as it is.

Comment: @iod  some of them don't have the format with r1-r10. I have 9 dummies in total. For example a male dummy that is equal to 1 for males and 0 for females. I also have two race dummies and 6 educational dummies equal to 1 if you did highschool, college, etc. These variables don't change over time but I still want 10 of them (they just don't vary across time)

Comment: @EmilKrabbe if you could share a sample of your actual dataframe that would be helpful, so we can see all the variations. Essentially, things that don't vary over time can be entered into the original `gather` call with a `-` in front of them, just like the "data" column in the code above, so it will look like this: `gather(time, ind, -data, -race, -gender)` - anything with a `-` will be replicated across all rows generated for that individual.

Comment: How do I share that ? Can I chat with you on this website ? I will add in my original post

Comment: @EmilKrabbe It is not a good practice to keep on changing questions especially after it has answered. You have already changed your question twice and now you want to change it again.I would suggest ask a new question with your updated information and please include data which is similar to your real data so you don't have to make changes again and again.

Comment: Yes I understand. I just added some pictures which I can delete after I understand the solution to including these dummies which don't start with "r"

Comment: like I said, all dummies should be included in the `gather` call with a `-` before them, then you shouldn't get an error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `melt` function from `data.table` and then `cbind`-

```
setDT(df)
df <- cbind(setnames(melt(df)[grep("^H_",variable),],"value","H"),
            setnames(melt(df)[grep("^W_",variable),],"value","W"))
df <- df[,Ind:=gsub(".*_","",data)] ##cleaning Ind_
df <- df[, time:=1:.N, by = .(Ind)]
df <- df[,.(time,W,H,Ind)]
```

Output-

```
> df
    time  W   H Ind
 1:    1 56 151   1
 2:    1 76 163   2
 3:    1 87 173   3
 4:    1 64 153   4
 5:    2 57 154   1
 6:    2 75 164   2
 7:    2 88  NA   3
 8:    2 66 154   4
 9:    3 56  NA   1
10:    3 76 165   2
11:    3 87  NA   3
12:    3 65 152   4
13:    4 56 153   1
14:    4 73 162   2
15:    4 85 172   3
16:    4 63 154   4
17:    5 55 152   1
18:    5 77 161   2
19:    5 84 171   3
20:    5 65 154   4
```